# Interfacing with Google spreadsheet via a Delphi client

Tags: delphi, google-sheets, google-docs

How do you interface with a Google spreadsheet using Delphi? Using a delphi client I would like to upload changes from a local database to a Google spreadsheet that everyone with an access to can view later. Similar to gspread (python) but for Delphi

Comment: I suspect there might be a Google API to interface with their docs. More research for you :). If there is already a similar product in python then why don't you have a look at how they did it.

Comment: none at the moment...I'm looking at the GData code now. Really easy to use in Python but will definitely take time to translate to delphi. Might have to use Python instead.